# Make a series of maps showing different rasters

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-pro

I have a set of rasters and I would like to create a series of maps, in which each page/map shows a different raster. The spatial extent is the same among all rasters. How could you achieve this in ArcGIS Pro?

I have looked into using the map series option, however it is focussed on the same items on the map but different spatial extents. I thought about making the map series index like a dummy: many pages which would focus on an identical area of interest. I know from ArcMap that it's possible to do page queries to only display data if a property matched with the data driven page. However, this only works for not-raster-features. I also stumbled upon Raster Catalogs which seemed to have potential but that is no longer supported in ArcGIS Pro.

Does anyone have an idea how I could achieve this in ArcGIS Pro?

Comment: An alternative to raster catalogs is a mosaic dataset. Explore that.

Comment: Try this one https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/220643/changing-global-template-features-to-reflect-in-other-maps/224186#224186 untested with pro though.

Comment: @FelixIP Thanks for the suggestion! I've got that working with ArcMap, and me and a coworker are now working on getting it working in ArcGIS Pro. I'll keep the question unanswered for now though, since so far it doesn't work in the program I want (yet).